# How to get key instead of key's value in a hash using Ruby and also omit the ":"

Tags: ruby, key-value, ruby-hash

So I have an example below :

```
movies = {
  dobby: "dobster is a lad",
  pirates_of_the_carribean: "Its all about jack sparrow kicking ass!"
  }
puts "what do you want to know about?\n
#{movies[:dobby]}. = 1\n
or...\n
#{movies[:pirates_of_the_carribean]}. = 2\n
Pick a number :"
```

Now what I get is the `value` of the key but I am looking to get the `Key` so that `puts` will output just the `key` and not the `value`.

I understand that the solution will likely output the key as `:key` and not `key` so id also like to know how to return a key without the ":" for displaying purposes.

Note : I have done thorough searching using google and haven't found a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

So I found my answer in a question that was asking something similar. To find just the key I used the `.keys[]` method my resulting code was this :

```
movies = {
  dobby: "dobster is a lad",
  pirates_of_the_carribean: "Its all about jack sparrow kicking ass!"
  }
puts "what do you want to know about?\n
#{movies.keys[0]}. = 1\n
or...\n
#{movies.keys[1]}. = 2\n
Pick a number :"
```

This code prints out the keys without the `:` and thus for `#{movies.keys[1]}` it prints out `pirates_of_the_carribean`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keys` method in `movies` hash:

```
movies = {
  dobby: "dobster is a lad",
  pirates_of_the_carribean: "Its all about jack sparrow kicking ass!"
}

puts "What do you want to know about?" 
counter=0
movies.keys.each do |k|
   counter += 1
   puts "#{k}. = #{counter} "
end 
puts "Pick a number:"
```